# Can't find object type as an add field option in Firebase

Tags: firebase, object, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firebase, and i am looking to add a field in my database which is an object.
I saw some tuts where there is an object option in the list but it's missing now.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is likely `map`. `map` is a key/value field type similar to an Object in Javascript or Dictionary in python.

Comment: I think this is the only relative option, but for some reason, when i choose a name for map such as sender , add fields and then save, it changes it value like autocorrect to sends, do you may know why is that happening?

Comment: That sounds like a local issue rather than a Firestore. Can you try another browser or device?